# How to add (x,y) coordinate value of each node in a graph data structure

Tags: python

I have a graph which data structure is as like below.

```
g = {1:[[2,4],[3,2]], 2:[[1,4],[3,1]], 3:[[1,2],[2,1]]}
```

graph's key represent nodes and values represent edge with their weight. At first I cleaned the data set by removing weight from the list. So, now the graph looks like below.

```
g = {1:[2,3], 2:[1,3], 3:[1,2]}
```

I need to use coordinate for every nodes to compute angle. How to I add coordinate herein? Please help me.

Comment: why dont you make the value a dictionary also. something like: `g = {1:[2:{"weight":4, "coord":{"x":1, "y":2}},3:{}],...}` or even better just store the nodes as objects

Answer (score 0):

Use dict comprehension.

```
>>> g = {1:[[2,4],[3,2]], 2:[[1,4],[3,1]], 3:[[1,2],[2,1]]}
>>> {x:[y[0] for y in g[x]] for x in g}
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2]}
```

This would give you the first item in each key value.

Comment: I have done this before but now I need to add coordinate value for each node

Comment: what do you mean by coordinate value?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this:

```
g = {1:[2,3], 2:[1,3], 3:[1,2]}
```

where the key is a node, and the value is a list of edges. You need to maintain multiple pieces of information for each node: coordinate of the node, and the list of edges. This can be done using nested dictionaries like this:

```
g = {1: {'coordinate': (10, 20), 'edges': [2, 3]},
     2: {'coordinate': (20, 10), 'edges': [1, 3]},
     3: {'coordinate': (30, -20), 'edges': [1, 2]},}
```

To get the coordinate and edges of node `3`:

```
x, y = g[3]['coordinate']
edges = g[3]['edges']
```